# How to remove '[' character from a string with re.sub function?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-re, square-bracket

I want to remove the '[' square bracket character from a string.
I am using re library.
I had no problems with this square bracket ']' but I still having problem with this square bracket '['.

My code:

```
depth_split = ['[575,0]']

new_string = re.sub(']','',depth_split) #working
newnew_string = re.sub('[','',new_string) #not working
```

PS: I'm using python.

The output that I have : ['[575,0']

The output that I expeting : ['575,0']

Comment: if you always want to replace "[" and "]" you dont need to use regex. you simply use `replace()`

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting an error given that you're trying to use `re.sub` on a list..

Comment: Do you know that a lot of characters (including `[` and `]`) have a special meaning in regular expressions?

Comment: The opening bracket `[` has special meaning in regexp, so it has to be escaped: `r"\["`. The closing bracket `]` also has special meaning, but only once an opening bracket has been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of using `regex` here since it can be done easily using `str.replace()`:

```
new_string= '[575,0]'
new_string = new_string.replace(']', '')
new_string = new_string.replace('[', '')
print(new_string)
```

But if using `regex` is necessary try:

```
import re

depth_split = '[575,0]'

new_string = re.sub(r'\]|\[','',depth_split) #working
print(new_string)
```

Comment: or `re.sub(r'[[\]]','',depth_split)`, or `depth_split.strip("[]")`

Comment: ... or if it is always the first and last character: `new_string[1:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern you seem to want here is `^\[|\]$`:

```py
depth_split = ['[575,0]']
depth_split[0] = re.sub(r'^\[|\]$', '', depth_split[0])
print(depth_split)  # ['575,0']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the brackets are always at the beginning and end of the strings in your list then you can do this with a string slice as follows:

```
depth_split = ['[575,0]']

depth_split = [e[1:-1] for e in depth_split]

print(depth_split)
```

**Output:**

```
['575,0']
```